# Finding nodes not matching query in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We have build up a NEO4j database with sample network data in it. We are currently trying to find a query to find NOT matching nodes.
We have 10 nodes in database and we get 8 of them by using the following query:

`match(n:nodeType)-[r:binded]-(m.nodetype2)-[z:binded]-(t:nodeType) where n.workingMode='Working' and t.workingMode='Protection' return n`

What we want is finding the two nodes which does not satify above condition.

I have found some entires mentioning the usage of NOT x IN y and tried a few solutions including

`match(a) where a.workingMode ='Working' 
match(n:nodeType)-[r:binded]-(m.nodetype2)-[z:binded]-(t:nodeType) where n.workingMode='Working' and t.workingMode='Protection'
and NOT a.id IN n.id
return a`

but that returns 10 and others i have tried provided either 10 or 0 results.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the result of your first statement to the second statement of the query as a list and then use `NOT IN` to exclude these nodes:

```
MATCH(n:nodeType)-[r:binded]-(m.nodetype2)-[z:binded]-(t:nodeType) 
WHERE n.workingMode='Working' AND t.workingMode='Protection'
WITH collect(n) as ns
MATCH (a:nodeType) 
WHERE a.workingMode ='Working' AND  NOT a IN  ns
RETURN a
```